# Intercept HTTP request body from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm aware that `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` allows a request to be intercepted, analyzed and blocked, but it only allows access to the request headers, and not the request body (as far as i know).

Sample use case: think intercepting form values.

It seems there is a API change proposal [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/notifications-of-web-request-and-navigation#TOC-Accessing-request-and-response-bodi) suggesting exactly this.

Is there another way this could be accomplished?

Thanks.

Comment: Intercepting response/request bodies is currently not possible using the built-in Chrome APIs. The [relevant part of the latest source code](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/web_request/) does not contain any signs of such a feature. If you can't live without the feature, you could either explore the [possibilities](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/npapi/info) of [NPAPI plugins](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html), or launch a (local) server, and redirect specific requests to your local server.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. NPAPI seems like overkill for my needs. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This functionality has been added to the API now, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest).

In order to access the body you need to do the following:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        console.log(details.requestBody);
    },
    {urls: ["https://myurlhere.com/*"]},
    ['requestBody']
);
```

Comment: Gee, that's awesome. Thanks for the ping.

Comment: For me it always return undefined. Maybe for beta channel only?

Comment: @BeauCielBleu there might be no request body. Try logging the URL instead: `console.log("url:"+details.url);`

Comment: Not working. There is only 'url', no 'requestBody' available.

Comment: @D09r, have you read the documentation? The requestBody property is optional, the documentation states "Only provided if extraInfoSpec contains 'requestBody'"

Answer (score 18):

Here is what I did

1. I used the `requestBody` to get the post requests body
2. I used a `decoder` the parse the body into a string

Here is an example

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(details.method == "POST")
        // Use this to decode the body of your post
            var postedString = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
                                      new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)));
           console.log(postedString)

    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```

Comment: Can also do `console.log(JSON.parse(postedString))` to parse the string as json

Answer (score 2):

While you may not be able to intercept, you can use standard AJAX approach to duct-tape it. Instead of making the href request see if you can make an asynchronous call and save it to an HTML object that isn't presented. Then scrape/read/parse/whatever your body criteria is, and if it passes, push that body object back up to the current window/page.

Storing the content in a suppressed element and then using that same element for content would allow you to avoid making duplicate calls. The downside is that you will get the full content for stuff you won't end up using. That may or may not be a bandwidth/speed performance issue.