# Getting Http request Body from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I know this question has already been asked before but my question is from a layman's perspective. I am trying to fetch the Http request body for a web page visited by chrome. When i researched online i got to know that there is a webRequest API for chrome which can be used. Also i got to know that we first have to write the below key,value in the manifest.json for using webrequest API.

```
"permissions": [
      "webRequest",
      "*://*.google.com/"
    ]
```

Also in the below link there is a piece of code which i understood can be used for the same.

[Intercept HTTP request body from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593853/intercept-http-request-body-from-chrome-extension)

But what i did not understand is where to write the code? Also could someone please let me know what i understood about manifest.json is correct or not?

I am a newbie to all this, as i was doing database stuff until now. Could some please explain in simple terms what has to be done to get the http request body from chrome? Also if there is a simple plugin which does the same then that would be a life saver. thanks.

Comment: This will probably be closed as "too broad", as your question does not exactly match the title. You are asking for generic help with Chrome Extensions. That said, a good place to start is the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview)

Answer (score 2):

Ok So i could not get an extension for chrome. But instead found fiddler. This is a stand alone app which intercepts all the requests and response from all Browsers. It can also intercept Http requests from Your Java App. Hurray!! Hopefully this helped someone. Thanks.